# Replace in sqlite Update is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, sqlite

I am using SQLite update with replace to replace the string in the column when i run the query it makes the other column to be [].can anyone tell me why it occurs like this.

Query:

```
  var old_farmerid = '"farmer_id":' + 1510829657942;
  var new_farmerid = '"farmer_id":' + 1933;
  var updateQuery = 'UPDATE load SET worker_details = replace(worker_details, ?, ?);';
  $log.log(updateQuery);
  return $cordovaSQLite.execute(Database.db, updateQuery, [old_farmerid, new_farmerid]).then(function (result) {
    $log.log('updated sucessfully', result);
  }, function (err) {
    $log.log('error in update is', err);
  });
```

And how can i make the old_farmerid to be like this '"farmer_id":1000'

Comment: Don't you need a where clause? Something like `WHERE farmer_id = 1000`. If you don't have a where any row in the table will be updated with the same data.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze i have used the where clause first but it makes all the data in that column to be [].

Comment: Whats about the `worker_details = replace(worker_details, ?, ?)`? Normally its `UPDATE tablename SET columnname = newvalue`. What do you expect from your syntax?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze it will replace the old value with the new value

Comment: Ok, but `worker_details` is one column and with what are you replacing it whats `replace(worker_details, ?, ?)` ?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze i am replacing the old_farmerid to new_farmerid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159159/discussion-between-kevinspaceyiskeysersoze-and-nidhin-kumar).